Who does the voice of the Lamp in the Aladdin short - Inside The Genie's Lamp
On the Aladdin DVD, there's a short, "Inside The Genie's Lamp", And I know I recognize the voice of the lamp, but I can't place it, nor can I find it online anywhere. All of the videos I see say that it's starring Gilbert Gottfried, who is the voice of Iago, not the lamp.



 or 


 


It sounds like Robin Leach who used to host lifestyles of the rich and famous.  I don't have a source, though.

@steelershark Indeed. And it is him, it's on several websites (like this one), so I think you can put this up, if you want.

The voice that you are referring to is that of Robin Leach.  He is mostly known (and his voice is most recognized) for hosting the television show Lifestyles of the Rich and Famous. 
Robin Leach is listed as narrating the 3D tour of the Genie's lamp:

Inside The Genie's Lamp, a 3D tour of the Genie's lamp with Robin
  Leach


It should also be noted that this tour is basically a parody of Lifestyles inside a lamp. Though I'm probably stating the obvious here. ;)
